# looping once over html as a string

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I try to read data from a table in html. I read periodically and the table length always change and I don't know its length. However the table is always on the same format so I try to recognize some pattern and read data based on it's position.
The html is of the form:

```
<head>
<title>Some webside</title>
</head>
<body 
<tr><td> There are some information coming here</td></tr>
<tbody><table>
<tr><td><a href="d?k=101">First</a></td><td>London</td><td>24</td><td>3</td><td>19:00</td><td align="center"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td><a href="d?k=102">Second</a></td><td>NewYork</td><td>24</td><td>4</td><td>20:13</td><td align="center"></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="d?k=201">Some surprise</a></td><td>Swindon</td><td>25</td><td>5</td><td>20:29</td><td align="center"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td><a href="d?k=202">Third</a></td><td>Swindon</td><td>24</td><td>6</td><td>20:45</td><td align="center"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<tr><td> There are some information coming here</td></tr>
</body>
```

I convert html to a string and go over it to read the data but I want to read it only once. My code is:

```
def ReadTable(m):
    refList = []
    firstId = 1
    nextId = 2
    k = 1
    helper = 1
    while firstId != nextId:
        row = []
        helper = m.find('<td><a href="d?k=', helper) + 17
        end_helper = m.find('">', helper)
        rowId = m[helper : end_helper]
        if k == 1:          # to check if looped again
            firstId = rowId
        else:
            nextId = rowId      
        row.append(rowId)
        helper = end_helper + 2
        end_helper = m.find('</a></td><td>', helper)
        rowPlace = m[helper : end_helper]
        row.append(rowPlace)
        helper = m.find('</a></td><td>', end_helper) + 13
        end_helper = m.find('</td><td>', helper)
        rowCity = m[helper : end_helper]
        row.append(rowCity)
        helper = end_helper + 9
        end_helper = m.find('</td><td>', helper)
        rowDay = m[helper : end_helper]
        row.append(rowDay)
        helper = end_helper + 9
        end_helper = m.find('</td><td>', helper)
        rowNumber = m[helper : end_helper]
        row.append(rowNumber)
        helper = end_helper + 9
        end_helper = m.find('</td>', helper)
        rowTime = m[helper : end_helper]
        row.append(rowTime)
        refList.append(row)
        k +=1
    return refList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filePath = '/home/m/workspace/Tests/mainP.html'
    fileRead = open(filePath)
    myString = fileRead.read()
    print myString
    refList = ReadTable(myString)
    print 'Final List = %s' % refList
```

I expect the outcome as a list with 4 lists inside like that:

`Final List = [['101', 'First', 'London', '24', '3', '19:00'], ['102', 'Second', 'NewYork', '24', '4', '20:13'], ['201', 'Some surprise', 'Swindon', '25', '5', '20:29'], ['202', 'Third', 'Swindon', '24', '6', '20:45']]`

I expect that after first loop the string is read again and the `firstId` is found again and my `while-loop` will terminate. Instead I have infinite loop and my list start to look like this:

`Final List = [['101', 'First', 'London', '24', '3', '19:00'], ['102', 'Second', 'NewYork', '24', '4', '20:13'], ['201', 'Some surprise', 'Swindon', '25', '5', '20:29'], ['202', 'Third', 'Swindon', '24', '6', '20:45'], ['me webside</title>\n</head>\n<body \n<tr><td> There are some information coming here</td></tr>\n<tbody><table>\n<tr><td><a href="d?k=101', 'First', 'London', '24', '3', '19:00'], ['102', 'Second', 'NewYork', '24', '4', '20:13']...`

I don't understand why my `helper` start to behave this way and I can't figure out how a program like that should be written. Can you suggest a good/effective way to write it or to fix my loop?

Comment: Better use a html parsing library like [`beautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking the return from your find and it is returning -1 when it doesn't find a match.
[http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find%20Return%20-1%20on%20failure)
Return -1 on failure

I updated this section of the code and it returns as you expect now. First and last row below match what you have above so you can find the replacement.

```
    row = []
    helper = m.find('<td><a href="d?k=', helper)
    if helper == -1:
        break
    helper += 17
    end_helper = m.find('">', helper)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you invest some time in looking at [LXML](http://lxml.de).  It allows you to look at all of the tables in an html file and work with the sub-elements of the things that make up the table (like rows and cells)

LXML is not hard to work with and it allows you to feed in a string with the

```
html.fromstring(somestring)
```

Further, there arte a lot of lxml questions that have been asked and answered here on SO so it is not to hard to find good examples to work from